# passing get parameters in a get parameter

Tags: html

I don't know if this is possible, and I'm sure i'm not calling it the right thing, but how can I pass a url with get parameter inside a get parameter itself? For example, I want to pass http://example.com/return/?somevars=anothervar as a value for the "return" parameter as show below:

http://example.com/?param1=4&return=http://example.com/return/?somevars=anothervar

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897480/pass-complex-url-as-parameter-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL-encode the inner parameter. How you do this depends on the language you're using, or if you're doing it by hand, so in the absence of information I'll just say that `?` is `%3F`, `&` is `%26` and `#` is `%23` - those are the only ones that are "required" for the browser to understand what you're doing.

Comment: wow. I thought I had tried that before, but I guess not. Thanks!