# Escaping ampersand in URL

Tags: http, url, get, query-string

I am trying to send a GET message that contains strings with ampersands and can't figure how to escape the ampersand in the URL.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com?candy_name=M&M
result => candy_name = M
```

I also tried:

```
http://www.example.com?candy_name=M\&M
result => candy_name = M\\
```

I am using URLs manually, so I just need the correct characters.

I can't use any libraries. How can it be done?

Answer (score 484, accepted):

They need to be percent-encoded:

```js
> encodeURIComponent('&')
"%26"
```

So in your case, the URL would look like:

```
http://www.example.com?candy_name=M%26M
```

Comment: :- %26 is not working for me. Is there any other solution.?

Comment: When i replace & to %26, its still showing the same error-- `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).`

Comment: @Sanjiv: That's a problem with your code, not percent encoding. Ask a question.

Comment: @Sanjiv make sure you replace "&" with "%26" first. 

See code:::

NSString *message = @"Hello Jack & Jill";
message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

        message = [message stringByAppendingString:@" "];
        message = [message stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Thank you for this! Saved me a ton of headache setting a database connection URI variable

Answer (score 50):

This does not *only apply* to the ampersand in URLs, but to all [reserved characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).  Some of which include:

```
# $ & + ,  / : ; = ? @ [ ]
```

The idea is the same as encoding an `&` in an HTML document, but the context has changed to be within the URI, in addition to being within the HTML document. So, the percent-encoding prevents issues with parsing inside of both contexts.

The place where this comes in handy a lot is when you need to put a URL inside of another URL. For example, if you want to post a status on Twitter:

```
http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?status=What%27s%20up%2C%20StackOverflow%3F(http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com)
```

There's lots of reserved characters in my Tweet, namely `?'():/`, so I encoded the whole value of the `status` URL parameter.  This also is helpful when using `mailto:` links that have a message body or subject, because you need to encode the `body` and `subject` parameters to keep line breaks, ampersands, etc. intact.

> When a character from the reserved set (a "reserved character") has
> special meaning (a "reserved purpose") in a certain context, and a URI
> scheme says that it is necessary to use that character for some other
> purpose, then the character must be percent-encoded. Percent-encoding
> a reserved character involves converting the character to its
> corresponding byte value in ASCII and then representing that value as
> a pair of hexadecimal digits. The digits, preceded by a percent sign
> ("%") which is used as an escape character, are then used in the URI
> in place of the reserved character. (For a non-ASCII character, it is
> typically converted to its byte sequence in UTF-8, and then each byte
> value is represented as above.) The reserved character "/", for
> example, if used in the "path" component of a URI, has the special
> meaning of being a delimiter between path segments. If, according to a
> given URI scheme, "/" needs to be in a path segment, then the three
> characters "%2F" or "%2f" must be used in the segment instead of a raw
> "/".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters

Comment: Among the above list, `! ' ( ) *` are not URL encoded using `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: there is a php function urlencode  which solves this problem : usage  $escapedfilename=urlencode($filename);

Answer (score 10):

I would like to add a minor comment to [Blender's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url/16622542#16622542).

You can do the following:

```js
var link = 'http://example.com?candy_name=' + encodeURIComponent('M&M');
```

That outputs:

```
http://example.com?candy_name=M%26M
```

The great thing about this it does not only work for `&`, but for any especial character.

For instance:

```js
var link = 'http://example.com?candy_name=' + encodeURIComponent('M&M?><')
```

Outputs:

```js
"http://example.com?candy_name=M%26M%3F%3E%3C"
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using `http://www.example.org?candy_name=M%26M`.

See also [this reference](http://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/url_encode.html) and some more information [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the % character to 'escape' characters that aren't allowed in URLs. See [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html).

A table of ASCII values is given on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set).

You can see `&` is 26 in hexadecimal - so you need M%26M.

Answer (score 4):

This may help if someone want it in PHP

```php
$variable = "candy_name=M&M";
$variable = str_replace("&", "%26", $variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use any libraries to encode the value,
http://www.urlencoder.org/ or http://www.urlencode-urldecode.com/ or ...

Just enter your value "M&M", not the full URL ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can rather pass your arguments using this encodeURIComponent function so you don't have to worry about passing any special characters.

```
data: "param1=getAccNos&param2="+encodeURIComponent('Dolce & Gabbana') OR
var someValue = 'Dolce & Gabbana';
data : "param1=getAccNos&param2="+encodeURIComponent(someValue)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent