# post symbol in query string in php

Tags: php, html

href='getprojmansub.php?mch_status='R&M'

It do not pass the value after & symbol in querystring how i can pass any symbol in query string in php.Is it posible to pass smbols like  # $ & * ( ) in query string in php.or any syntax for passing symbols.

Comment: Go to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url) . I think there is something you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$status = $_POST['mch_status'];
echo htmlentities($status);
```

Answer (score 0):

var_dump(urlencode("M&M"));
string(5) "M%26M"