# How I get value "&" QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my Query string URL

```
http/test.com/VoucherToHotel.aspx?Hotel_Name=Biverah%20Hotel%20&%20Suites&Ckeck_In=11/05/2014
```

my problem is when i retrieve Hotel_Name. Hotel name is "Biverah Hotel & Suites"

```
string Hotel_Name = Request.QueryString["Hotel_Name"];
string Check_In = Request.QueryString["Ckeck_In"];
```

But string Hotel_Name value is only "Biverah Hotel". its not showing "& Suites". Is querySrting not Support "&" or how i get "&" value.

string Check_In is fine.

Comment: it's asp.net, so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url does not really apply

Answer (score 5):

You have to encode the '&' in the query, like you encode ' ' (space character) as %20. Use %26 : http://p2p.wrox.com/html-code-clinic/5699-ampersand-query-string.html