# Unable to post & symbol in facebook

Tags: android, facebook

While posting a string containing & symbol to facebook, in facebook page it is displaying the string content before the & symbol and the string after the & symbol is missing(including &).
Any Idea ...
Please Help,Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using &amp; instead.

Comment: already tried but not working

Comment: Or possibly `%26` as stated in the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url

Answer (score 2):

URL encode the `&` as `%26`.

Consider using `URLEncoder` to encode other special characters, too.

As such the `&` is a URL metacharacter that separates parameters from each other.