# Open email client with custom predefined email text in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send an email using jquery. Here is my code

```
$text = "mailto:info@diadori.com?subject=The Vow Engagement Ring Finder&body=" . "Hi, I found an engagement ring that I love and want to know what you think. To see the ring download the iPhone app named <The Vow Engagement Ring Finder> iPhone - http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=509902433&mt=8 - Android - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diadori.thevow. View the ring: ". $rings[0]['ringThumbNailImagePath'] . "</html>";

    $bodytag = str_replace(" ", "%20", $text );
```

in jquery

```
window.location.herf = $bodytag;
```

It works fine, HoWever text is shown only upto id=509902433 , because of & it stops there. I have tried placing html tags but not working.

How can I custom place a message in mailto.
secondly is there any way to add attachment?

Comment: @pmandell i need to open email client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percent-encode it:

```
... ects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=509902433%26mt=8 - Androi ...
```

not:

```
... ects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=509902433&mt=8 - Androi ...
```

So:

See this related topic: [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: Damn, why it didn't occur to me -.-'. How can i add attachment and do u know the ascii for "Enter"

Comment: Are you trying to add an attachment to a an email from a user's locally installed email application?

Comment: You can't add an attachment with a mailto.  Among other things, the file would have to exist on the client's machine: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html  I wonder if you can't re-think the solution to what you are trying to do.