# How do I properly encode a url containing an ampersand in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, urlencode, url-encoding

How do I properly encode the following url?

```
http://mysite/myapp/content/Documents/Opening Leave Case for Supervisors-WC&TW.pdf
```

When I view the url after url encoding the file name I get this error:

> "The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence."

I'm certain that the problem lies with the ampersand in the file name but am unsure how to properly deal with it.

Here is what I have so far (that is not working):

```
string.Concat( "~/Content/Documents/", HttpUtility.UrlEncode( ContentLocation ) );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [escaping ampersand in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: Where in code did you get the error from? (I'm sure it wasn't directly from the URL encoding.)

Comment: Jashaszun - I updated my question with more details on how I generate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode which transforms spaces to "%20" instead of "+". Other than that I see nothing wrong with what you're doing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Also you'll need to post the context of where this error is occurring because the error doesn't occur on the conversion obviously.