# &amp; W3C validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation, ampersand

I got to improve some website. The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) shows me a problem with `&amp;`:

> `&` did not start a character reference. (`&` probably should have been escaped as `&amp;`.)

What is weird, in my code I use `$amp;`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans%7COpen+Sans:400,600,700%7COswald&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" >
```

I read a lot of articles, support topics, but I can't find the solution. Someone knows the solution?

Comment: Easy, don't listen to w3c validator anymore :D

Comment: replace `&` with `&amp;` in page

Comment: it seems to be already &amp: `Oswald&amp;subset`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR if you check code which I paste in post you will see that I did this

Comment: @user3921877 it'll sound funny but sadly in some cases page that pass in 100% w3c validator... is a page that doesn't work :) Use this validator as a comment on your code, not as a review of it. Escpecially as it doesn't cover changes from HTML5 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I put your `link` in the online [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) as follow and it passes. You may need to put more code for us to check it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.comcss?family=Noto+Sans%7COpen+Sans:400,600,700%7COswald&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" >
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And make sure your `link` tag is in the header section.

Comment: This is only a part of my code, when I put url address there I got this error

Comment: if you copy-paste the code I put here as is and check on validator, you'll see it passes. Please provide more information/code to check it thoroughly. Thanks