# How to Use "&" in the URL?

Tags: url

I have a clothing brand Ace & Jig listed in my brand list. I'd like the users to be able to go to the brand's product page by linking it to "http://www.achengshop.com/collections/vendors?q=ace+&+jig", but the "&" seems to get ignored. How could you use "&" in the url?

Comment: possible duplicate of [escaping ampersand in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. It is a reserved word. But you can percent encode it: Just use this '%26' in place of the ampersand (without quotes).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the ampersand with `%26`, since it is a reserved character used as a separator for GET parameters. For example, here's your URL with the ampersand properly escaped:

```
http://www.achengshop.com/collections/vendors?q=ace+%26+jig
```