# When message include like & sended by http how i handling?

Tags: http, parameters

I want to send message by HTTP.
But I have a problem .
If message include like & this is not working well.

for example , I send like this
 a=111111&222222&b=3333333

results what i want 
a=111111&222222
b= 333333

But result is 
a= 111111
b= 333333

how i handling what i want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your values. `&` becomes `%26`, so your query should be `a=111111%26222222&b=3333333`

See this link for details: [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)