# Java how to escape "&" character in url params?

Tags: java

```
String urlParameters = "login=test&password=te&ff";
```

I have a String urlParams, & - is part of the password, how to make it escaped, thus not be recognized as a separator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [escaping ampersand in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: why is this being upvoted when it displays a blatant lack of research?

Comment: @WimOmbelets He either has friends, or there's a bunch of new people currently online. Either way, it happens all the time. Simply vote to close as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Use a URL Encoder on each of the components: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: but again will he recognize the & symbol?, that is not a separator?

Comment: You encode each component separately: you encode the login, the password, then build the url. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Encode your password using [URLEcoder#encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with utf-8

```
String urlParameters = "login=test&password="+
                  URLEncoder.encode("te&ff", "UTF-8");
```