# When sending XML by POST, the symbol & is escaping entire rest of string

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a string formatted as XML to a Web Api controller, and when it is sent, it only receives the string up to the first `&` symbol, and then cuts off. Is there any way to make sure the `&` symbols will not escape the string?

Here is an example of my request:

```
string result = "";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

     string allLines = "=" + param.ToString();
     result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", allLines);
}   
return result;
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the data causing the issue?  Is the ampersand `&` or `&amp;` (or some similar special character code)?

Comment: It's `&lt;` that is causing the issue

Comment: Is this data being passed via the URL?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16622542/361842

Comment: No, it is being passed via HTTP Header.

Comment: @JohnLBevan That link helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP header sometimes is not just key-value pair. It can be an array of values divided by `&` character.

Try to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)` when sending value and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value)` when receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Try Uri.EscapeUriString or HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode.  Alternately, you can manually encode an ampersand by replacing it with %26.  For instance:

```
myString.Replace("&", "%26");
```