# In express , get request.query containing special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/medicine_alternatives/?id=Avinim%20Plus%20(100%20&%20500)`

For clarity ,the parameter without applying encoding is `id=Avinim Plus (100 & 500)`

At server I am retreiving the parameter as follows:

```
app.get('/medicine_alternatives', function (req, res) {
    console.log('id='+req.query.id);
});
```

I am getting `id=Avinim Plus (100` in the console .It seems that it is treating everything after `&` as different parameter.

How do I get the whole string `Avinim Plus (100 & 500)`?

Comment: You'll have to encode the params while constructing the URL. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16622504/1782481

Comment: You must encode the `&` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is the delimiter for separating query string parameters. A query string parser would parse that as:

```
{
    "id": "Avinim Plus (100",
    " 500)": undefined
}
```

Since `&` is a special character, you need to uriencode it by replace it with `%26`:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/medicine_alternatives/?id=Avinim%20Plus%20(100%20%26%20500)