# Breeze.js: Ampersand character ("&") in where clause throws error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze, breeze-sharp

Here is the JavaScript code to create my Breeze query:

```
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("suppliers").
            where("Name", op.Contains, "&").
            select("Name").
            orderBy("Name").
            take(50);
```

When I send this query, I receive this error: "The query specified in the URI is not valid."

In Fiddler I can see the URI, but it seems to be ok:
http://localhost:59994/breeze/FastSearch/suppliers?$filter=substringof(%27%26%27%2CName)%20eq%20true&$orderby=Name&$top=50&$select=Name

I receive this error alway when my search pattern contains a '&' character.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try percent-encoding the ampersand:

where("Name", op.Contains, "%26")

See this answer:
[escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: As you can see in my question, the ampersand was already escaped in the uri: ...$filter=substringof(%27%26%27%2CName)...