# Send array of objects from angular to Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have tried to send it like this:

```
$scope.listDms = []
$http.post('url?listDomain='+$scope.listDms);
```

in spring controller

```
@RequestMapping('url')
public getDomains(@RequestParam List<Domain> listDomain){
...
}
```

but the app can't bind from String to List

Comment: Yes, It can't. What is your question?

Comment: How i can do it ??

Comment: Send list in body of your request.

Comment: Since it is post request you can send it in request body

Comment: You should send it in the POST body

Comment: Thank you, this is wath i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to send array in the body of request

```
$scope.listDms = []
$http.post('url',$scope.listDms);
```

in spring controller

```
@RequestMapping('url')
public getDomains(@RequestBody List<Domain> listDomain){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a post request you can send it in request body but if you have to send the data as url paramter you need to serialize the data before sending.

```
$http.post('url?listDomain='+JSON.stringify($scope.listDms));
```

However if the data consists any of the reserved special characters like '?,&,/....' you then need to escape your data before sending it to server side.

[Escaping special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)