# Django login "?next=" only saving one GET parameter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) `1.10` and [Python Social Auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) `0.1.0`.

I use Django login view, having only added the template with:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'azuread-oauth2' %}{% if request.GET.next %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}{% endif %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-windows" aria-hidden="true"></i> {% trans 'Login' %}</a>
```

This works fine if my `?next=` is something like:

- `app/something/`
- `app/something/?info=blue`

But it doesn't work for:

- `app/something/?info=blue&moreinfo=red`

What happens is that the redirect is done to: `app/something/?info=blue`.

Is there any reason for the redirect to fail for more than one GET parameter?
I've tested several times (different apps, and also with Django `1.9` and this happens always).

This is a big problem because I'm building an APIusing [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/). Having an API that may use another to log in (two oauth2 in a row) requires several parameters (`?client=fasa&....`) to be saved in the next variable.

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from the fact that the & doesn't know which get it relates to (and must default to the outer most)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [escaping ampersand in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: I'll leave my answer for the time being but it appears as though you need to use `%26` and not the html code as I suggest below

Comment: I'm testing it, I will comment it shortly

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll delete my answer. I only left it up whilst I wasn't sure if you had read it

Comment: You may answer with ``%26``. I don't think it should be considered a duplicate because I spent at least one hour searching and couldn't find the other question. Because I didn't knew the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as stated by [@Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse), is related to the encoding of the URL.

In Django, this is already taken care of. And so making the call `app/something/?info=blue&moreinfo=redand` redirected to login, as:

```
myapp.com/login?=next=app/something/%3Finfo=blue%26moreinfo=red
```

This happens since Django methods login_required and LoginRequiredMixin already encodes the URL. This is great because ìt makes `{{ request.GET.next }}` recognize as `next` the complete redirect URL.

The problem is then in `{{ request.GET.next }}` that "unencodes the URL".

The problem is solved with [urlencode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode), doing `{{ request.GET.next|urlencode }}`:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'azuread-oauth2' %}{% if request.GET.next %}?next={{ request.GET.next|urlencode }}{% endif %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-windows" aria-hidden="true"></i> {% trans 'Login' %}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the related question [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url), you will see that there are a selection of reserved characters which include ampersand

```
 # $ & + ,  / : ; = ? @ [ ]
```

These characters need to be percent encoded in order to be included/escaped.

Thus your url needs to escape these characters, for example

```
app/something/?info=blue%26moreinfo=red
```

You may also be able to use the `urlencode` function - See [How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607551/1324033)

```
>>>import urllib
>>>urllib.urlencode({'next': 'app/something/?info=blue&moreinfo=red'})
'next=app%2Fsomething%2F%3Finfo%3Dblue%26moreinfo%3Dred'
```

---

For templates, django has the [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) template tag, which [eventually uses pythons built in `urllib`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/http.py#L54) to achieve the same thing as the above python code

```
{{ request.GET.next|urlencode }}
```

Comment: Django already does that encoding, the problem continues... I've updated my question, please see if you can help me as I've already accepted the answer.

Comment: @NBajanca - I see, I'll try to see if I can find a better solution than "make a custom template tag" if I get some time to properly look into it. In the mean time, you may unaccept this answer if you wish.

Comment: problem solved with ``{{ request.GET.next|urlencode }}``. I can't believe I spent so much time doing this.... If you want you can update your answer. I will remove the Update when you update the answer as it should be part of it.

Comment: @NBajanca - I've added it to my answer but it feels to me as though it might be better as a self answered question since you were the one that did the research into it and should receive the credit as such :)