# php GET variable gets interrupted with ampersand (&)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

**SOLUTION:**

it seems htaccess requires 'B' for it to retain the ampersand
so using

`RewriteRule ^album/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)$ view.php?album=$1 [L,B]`

works

**SOLUTION**

I am trying to read the get value from the url which is:

```
view.php?album=something
```

This is one of my rules in my **.htaccess** file:

```
#this rewrite 'view.php?album=something' to 'album/something'
RewriteRule ^album/([^/\.]+)/?$ ^view.php?album=$1 [L]
```

The problem is that sometimes the album name ie **'something'** may contain and & in the name and this causes $_GET to trip up.

```
**For example** 
album name is 'football&basketball'

The view.php page will only read up to football and throw an error.
```

Without the rewrite rule it works perfectly fine, but with the rewrite rule it messes up for that one case.

I am using **rawurlencode** at the moment

**If there is no & in the name then it also works fine - its only with the & when it messes up**

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to overcome this? I have tried using htmlspecialchars and htmlentities etc.

**EDIT: Added Code**

**htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#rewrite view.php?album=whatever to album/whatever
RewriteRule ^album/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)$ view.php?album=$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /ShyamJoshi/dist/ 

#remove .php and .html extension
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]


RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*) 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [QSA,L] 

</IfModule>
```

**PHP:**

This function is being used twice. First it shows all directories and then it shows all images in directories (which is the 'else' part)

```
function getImagesOrImageDirs($dirOnly) {
    $dirLoc = getcwd() . '/images/events/';

    $allDirs = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dirLoc));

    echo '<div class="row">';
    if ($dirOnly == true) {
      foreach($allDirs as $dir) {
        $innerDirImages = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dirLoc.'/'.$dir));
        $firstImageOfDir = reset($innerDirImages);

        /* view.php?album=something -> rewritten by htaccess to albums/something*/
        $href = 'album/'.$dir;

        // $href = 'album/'.$dir;
        $imageSrc = 'images/events/'.$dir.'/'.$firstImageOfDir;

        echo albumAndPhotoTemplate($href, $imageSrc, true, $dir, 'col-xs-12 col-sm-3');
      }
    } else {
      if (empty ($_GET['album']) ) {
        return ;
      }
      $albumName = $_GET['album'];
      print_r($albumName);
      $dirLoc = $dirLoc .'/'.$albumName;
      $allImages = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dirLoc));

      foreach($allImages as $image) {
        $imgSrcAndHref = 'images/events/'.$albumName.'/'.$image;
        echo albumAndPhotoTemplate($imgSrcAndHref, $imgSrcAndHref, false, '',  'col-xs-12, col-sm-3');
      }
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^album/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)$ view.php?album=$1 [L]
```

Get your variable using

```
$_GET['album'];
```

If you want to both variable and name:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

To escape `&` on url use `%26` like this..

```
view.php?album=something%26basketball
```

See more here [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: the rewrite engine is already on and I am using $_GET. When I "$_GET" the variable it cuts it and I only get it the value upto the &

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but doing print_r($_GET) still gets the string up to &

Comment: use `football%26basketball` in url.

Comment: I have tried the answer above and I can't seem to get it working. I have added my code above as well