# Get two URL parameters - but need to preserve & symbol

Tags: javascript, url-parameters, uriencoding

I need to get two parameters from a URL, and they could potensially contain an & symbol or a space. as part of the search string.

Example: `mysite.com?param1=Bower & Wilkins?param2=Speakers`

I realize that Bower & Wilkins contains the obvious symbol for getting the second parameter, but can I replace it with something else?

When trying this function, can easily return a single parameter:

```
URL: mysite.com?param1=Bower%20&%20Wilkins

function getQueryStringValue(key) {
  return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
}
var param1 = getQueryStringValue("param1"); // Bower & Wilkins
```

How can I get the second parameter and how must I construct the URL. Can I use another symbol than & for listing the second parameter?

What I need:

`var param1 = getQueryStringValue("param1"); // Bower & Wilkins`

`var param2 = getQueryStringValue("param2"); // Speakers`

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url) is a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` within the param needs to be encoded as `%26`.  This means you need to substitute
before running the parameters through encodeURI or use encodeURIComponent on the value.

The input should be `"mysite.com?param1=Bower%20%26%20Wilkins&param2=Speakers"`.

To get the result you could try something like this

```
function getQueryStringValue(url, key) {
    var params = {};
    var url_params = url.split("?", 2);
    if (url_params.length > 1) {
        var param_list = url_params[1].split("&");
        param_list.map(function (param_str) {
            var kv = param_str.split("=", 2);
            params[kv[0]] = kv[1];
        });
    }
    return (key in params)? decodeURIComponent(params[key]) : ''
}

var url = "mysite.com?param1=Bower%20%26%20Wilkins&param2=Speakers";
console.log("Bower & Wilkins" === getQueryStringValue(url, "param1"));
console.log("Speakers" === getQueryStringValue(url, "param2"));
console.log("" === getQueryStringValue(url, "param3"));
```