# How to pass string with & via get in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, I wonder if someone could help me, I need to pass a string that contains (&) via get. Example:

.com/index.php?nome=name=AA&BB&age=18&city=....

This way the name arrives from the other sides only AA

Comment: Try this: var url = 'com/index.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent('AA&BB') + '&age=18&city=....';

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url   

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode the parameter before sending it to the server:

```
var url = "normal url?" + encodeURIComponent("get params");
```