# How to handle an un-encoded special character in a url query string?

Tags: php, url, get, query-string, url-encoding

I have a url like this:

```
http://www.nearbynursinghomes.com/innerpage.php?state=CA&city=RIVERSIDE&shop=ALTA%20VISTA%20HEALTHCARE%20&%20WELLNESS%20CENTRE
```

I'm currently using this code:

```
$category = $_GET["state"];
$city= $_GET["city"];
$shop= $_GET["shop"];
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 

$start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM $datatable 
    WHERE STATE='$category'
    AND CITY='$city'
    AND PROVNAME='$shop'
    ORDER BY PROVNAME ASC LIMIT $start_from, $results_per_page" ;
$rs_result = $conn->query($sql);
```

However it doesn't return the proper value because of the `&` in the middle of the value which says `shop=ALTA%20VISTA%20HEALTHCARE%20&%20WELLNESS%20CENTRE`.

It just gets cut off. How would I fix this?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16622542/1484621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good nights rest i came up with this solution using the tools provided here.

```
$shop= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$shop= explode("=", $shop,4);
$shop= $shop[3];
$shop= urldecode("$shop");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a malformed querystring in your url.  You should do everything in your power to correct this at its source.

If you are unable to do so, then a workaround is the best you can do.

This is not a particularly efficient method, nor a simple pattern ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SkbVzt/2)), but it will work on your sample string.

You can leverage `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or whatever you wish to capture your url, then use this `preg_match()` method ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fd5b4d5270fbfe549b6806119cdeed45d54b159)):

```
$url=urldecode('http://www.nearbynursinghomes.com/innerpage.php?state=CA&city=RIVERSIDE&shop=ALTA%20VISTA%20HEALTHCARE%20&%20WELLNESS%20CENTRE');
if(preg_match_all('/(?<=[?&])([^=]+)=\K[^=]+(?=&|$)/',$url,$qs)){
    //              key------^^^^^^^   ^^^^^-------value
    $array=array_combine($qs[1],$qs[0]);
    var_export($array);
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'state' => 'CA',
  'city' => 'RIVERSIDE',
  'shop' => 'ALTA VISTA HEALTHCARE & WELLNESS CENTRE',
)
```

Then you can reference those array elements when you write your MySQLi **prepared statements** with **placeholders**.

---

If you are happy to access the other key-value pairs with `$_GET` and only want to extract the `shop` value then this is simple/direct way:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1ac33e604e472b74e3dbfa17575bd0434cf4900))

```
$url = urldecode('http://www.nearbynursinghomes.com/innerpage.php?state=CA&city=RIVERSIDE&shop=ALTA%20VISTA%20HEALTHCARE%20&%20WELLNESS%20CENTRE&page=4');
echo preg_match('~[?&]shop=\K[^=]+(?=&|$)~', $url, $out) ? $out[0] : '[fail]';
```

Output:

```
ALTA VISTA HEALTHCARE & WELLNESS CENTRE
```

([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SkbVzt/4))

Comment: @Charles thanks for the upvote.  I have extended my answer to include a simpler, `shop`-specific solution.