# Requests.get not working with & character

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm doing a requests.get call with the following url:

```
https://api.datasource.com/apps/ios/ranking?countries=NL&categories=Overall > Kids > 5 & Under&device=ios&ranks=1000
```

I get an error message with `"categories" has an illegal value "Overall` which is due to the & sign in Overall > Kids > 5 **&** Under

What's the best approach for escaping this character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of passing the query parameters directly in the URL, `requests` [lets you pass them](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) in a dictionary `params` and will handle the URL encoding. (In this case, you need to escape the ampersand.)

```
In [15]: params = dict(countries='NL', categories='Overall > Kids > 5 & Under', device='ios', ranks=1000)

In [16]: requests.get("http://www.example.com", params=params)
Out[16]: <Response [200]>
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!