# Why is query string's = and & not encoded?

Tags: php, http

Why do we not encode = and & in query strings? I am referencing [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) but cannot find where it says that we should not encode these characters.  Using Guzzle, it doesn't seem they encode anything really.

Take for example the `query string: key1='1'&key2='2'`, shouldn't this be encoded as `key1%3D%271%27%26key2%3D%272%27`?  If I plug `key1='1'&key2='2'` into chrome as a query string (e.g. `www.google.com?key1='1'&key2='2'`), it appears as `key1=%271%27&key2=%272%27`, which does not match guzzle.  Guzzle outputs `key1='1'&key2='2'`.  Guzzle's encoding algorithm is below:

```
private static $charUnreserved = 'a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.~';

private static $charSubDelims = '!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=';

public function encode()
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/(?:[^' . self::$charUnreserved . self::$charSubDelims . '%:@\/\?]++|%(?![A-Fa-f0-9]{2}))/',
        function ($match) {
            return urlencode($match[0]);
        },
        $str
    );
}
```

Comment: Well, `&` and `=` *means* something specific in URLs. It depends on what exactly you it to mean. Literally "&" and "="? Or parameter separators?

Comment: @deceze, parameter separators.  But I cannot find that in RFC 3986 where it refers to those specific characters.

Comment: I have no idea what Guzzle is. But as a general rule, the idea is that a URL has a series of keys/values following the ?. The pairs are separated with & - so that & is NOT encoded but all OTHER & are encoded. The key & value are separated by = so that = is NOT encoded but all OTHER = are encoded. If the & separating parameters or the = separating key and value in a parameter were themselves encoded then you would just have one giant key with no value.

Comment: I'm confused by your example, which seems to be about escaping single quotes (`'`), which is a completely different question from the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` and `&` don't have any special meaning as part of URL syntax. As far as URL syntax is concerned, they're just ordinary characters.

However, when used in query strings, there's a convention implemented by most application frameworks to use them to delimit parameters and values. If you want to use these characters literally in a parameter name or value, you need to encode them. See [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)