# POST special characters to MVC via json

Tags: json, model-view-controller, urlencode

I'm sending a parameter to my Controller via json which contains and ampersand and the string gets cut off after that character. Been searching for hours and cannot find a solution.

**JavaScript**

```
var url = '/Common/DownloadFile?fileName=Me&You.xlsx';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    // Here the param is coming in as 'Me'
    // Code removed for clarity
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the used server side language? I guess .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In urls & needs to be escaped because it is used to add new params like

`http://hello.com"?fileName=Something&otherFileName=SomethingElse`

You need to escape the ampersand by percent encoding it like this:

`/Common/DownloadFile?fileName=Me%26You.xlsx`

Here is more information on url parameter escaping [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: Perfect, issue was I was using encodeURIComponent() around the entire url but it worked after doing `code`var url = fileUrl + '?fileName=' + encodeURIComponent('Me&You.xlsx')`code`

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand is used to separate arguments in a URL. If you want the ampersand to be part of a parameter value, you need to URLencode it using a method like encodeURIComponent().

In this particular case, the encoded version of Me&You.xslx would be Me%26You.xlsx. If you specify that in your GET request your application should get the expected value.