# How to pass multiple parameters with some parameter having operator sign like '+' or '&'

Tags: javascript

I try to make shopping cart with case below:

I have button onclick=addItem(action,cat_no) Will fire this function when click:

```
function addItem(action,cat_no) {
    switch(action) {
        case "adds":
            queryString = 'action='+action+'&cat_no='+cat_no;
             execute ajax adds...}
        break;
        case "drop":
            queryString = 'action='+action+'&cat_no='+cat_no;
             execute ajax drop...}
```

This function pass the value to php script.

I found that if I have the item with  cat_no having '+' and '&' will fail.

For Example let say: cat_no = 'SS+03L',

I believe it is because when it puts this value into the queryString, the '+' became the operator instead of value:

```
queryString = 'action='adds'&cat_no='SS+03L;
```

(When I check echo $_GET['cat_no'] I only get 'SS' instead of 'SS+03L')

In this case, what can I do to make sure the 'SS+03L' can be put correctly into the query and pass to the php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First You require to encode that operator characters using encodeURIComponent() **in javascript**

```
encodeURIComponent( 'SS+03L') // will be "SS%2B03L" then pass to php

//in your case> queryString = 'action='+action+'&cat_no='+encodeURIComponent(cat_no);
```

> and then 'if you require' to decode **in php** you can do it using urldecode() to get original  string back

```
urldecode("SS%2B03L") /*you will get 'SS+03L' back and construct your query then*/
```

hope it helps!

Comment: I only use:    queryString = 'action='+action+'&cat_no='+encodeURIComponent(cat_no);    It already works, how come? no need to urldecode at php.

Comment: Do I really need urldecode in  php? If not then what is that for?

Comment: I jsut check php manual says: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.

Comment: well @P.Lau thank you for reading docs. actually i'm formally python guy now i and just forgot that part :P