# Unable to retain special characters in expressjs router URL request

Tags: express

Im trying to query a record from database using this criteria: **VITAMINS + ZINC 100MG/10MG PER 5ML SYRUP**

This is what my request url looks like:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/search?key=VITAMINS%20+%20ZINC%20100MG/10MG%20PER%205ML%20SYRUP
```

Here is my express router looks like:

```
router.get('/search', (req, res, next) => {
  const query = req.query;
  console.log(query.key);

  .... omitted

});
```

The problem here is i can't retain the `+` special character and thus end up getting this log printed which is not the original criteria inside the router.

```
VITAMINS   ZINC 100MG/10MG PER 5ML SYRUP
```

Comment: Did you tried encoding the query string ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url

Comment: i tried decodeURIComponent but still the same as the logged output

Comment: I meant, if you have control of code generating the URL, you can use `encodeURIComponent()` at client side combined with decoding at server side.

Comment: @Ankit hey i was able to solve my problem and thanks to your idea. first i did a `encodeURIComponent` in the client then does a `decodeURIComponent` in the server to render the same criteria

Comment: lot of thanks... mind to make that an answer? will gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of URI, `+` character is one of the [reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

> When a character from the reserved set (a "reserved character") has
>   special meaning (a "reserved purpose") in a certain context, and a URI
>   scheme says that it is necessary to use that character for some other
>   purpose, then the character must be percent-encoded.

In your case, query string needs to be percent-encoded before hitting the URL at client side :

> encodeURIComponent("VITAMIN + ZINC")

And then at server side (i.e. express) decode the query using `decodeURIComponent()`.