# How to get the right query of an url that has a query in the string?

Tags: javascript

I've got a query inception problem.

I want to add this url

```
let url = "https://example.com/?1sCmRaAAAA72SeRa7wRVoddtJBRw&3u2500&4u1500&5m1&2e1&key=somekey-5o-Wj4&callback=none&token=106953"
```

to window.location as a query.

```
window.location = `/find/?photo=${url}`;
```

The result is unfortunately:

```
photo=https://example.com/?1sCmRaAAAA72SeRa7wRVoddtJBRw
```

so the &s are missing to the query what is need to get the image.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question. I'm pretty sure that it has been answered, but I just can't get the name for this problem to find it.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url) is what you are looking for

Comment: The solution to avoid this problem, is to use the backslash escape character.

The backslash \ escape character turns special characters into string characters
Example : The sequence \"  inserts a double quote in a string:

Comment: @Pavlo that was the tip! encodeURIComponent() works perfect

Comment: @Shadrix `encodeUri` works on the entire string, so you don't have to do it manually for `&`