# Angular 9 how to handle ampersand(&) inside activated route param field

Tags: angular, url, urlencode

I am fetching query parameter from url through `ActivatedRoute` `queryParams`  method.It is working fine for normal string.But If I have '&' inside the query value,then it's split the value from '&' and getting the string before the '&' position.Example is below:

`http://localhost:4200/#/test/APP?cat1=APP1&cat2=A&B%20Test=&cat3=Service` this is the url from which I'm fetching the `cat1`,`cat2`,,`cat3` value.

```
constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute){
}
this.actRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     this.catName1 = params['cat1'];
     this.catName2 = params['cat2'];
     this.catName3 = params['cat3'];
     console.log(this.catName1, this.catName2);
})
```

`this.catName1` is printing `APP1` but `this.catName2` is printing only `A`, rest of the part is omitted.How to get the whole `this.catName2` value as `A&B Test`. I already tried with `encodeURI()` function but nothing happened.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is working as it should. `&` is used to separate query parameters in an URL. As such `&` has a special meaning in an URL. (Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) If your values have `&` in them, they should be URL encoded before being used.

To URL encode a string you can do in the browser console, `encodeURI("<<URL>>")`.
The encoded version of your URL will be,

```
http://localhost:4200/#/test/APP?cat1=APP1&cat2=A&B%20Test=&cat3=Service
```

`encodeURI` however does not encode, `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`. Since one of your query params has `&` use `encodeURIComponent` instead. Note that
`encodeURIComponent` should be used on the individual query params and not on the URL itself.

```
const params = {
  cat1: "APP1",
  cat2: "A&B Test",
  cat3: "Service"
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
  params[key] = encodeURIComponent(value);
}

console.log(params); // prints Object { cat1: "APP1", cat2: "A%26B%20Test", cat3: "Service" }

this.router.navigate(['/test/APP'], { queryParams: params });
```

Comment: This url is same as of mine.Also I told that I alredy used `encodeURI()` and nothing happened.