# Using ampersand in Powershell parameter string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that uses an URL as parameter. Those URLs often have ampersands &. When trying to give an URL with an ampersand I get the following error:

```
.\test.ps1 -link http://testurl&qdfq
```

```
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quot
ation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

I understand that I can workaround this with using double quotes in the string for example:

```
.\test.ps1 -link "http://testurl&qdfq"
```

But I don't understand that the $link parameter needs this, as it is defined as as a string:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$link
)

Write-information $link -informationaction Continue
```

Is there another parameter I need to use in stead of [string] to make the command works without double quotes? So I can use:

```
.\test.ps1 -link http://testurl&qdfq
```

Comment: [Escape the ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16622542/1701026)? `.\test.ps1 -link http://testurl%26qdfq`

Comment: You might also use single quotes: `.\test.ps1 -link 'http://testurl&qdfq'`

Comment: Thx @iRon, though I'm trying to make the script more user friendly so people don't have to use escape chars, or single/double quotes.

Comment: don't tag spam. Version-specific tags are only used for problems only occur in those version. Please remove the irrelevant tags

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a PowerShell *metacharacter*: a character with special meaning when used in *unquoted* contexts.

Therefore, to use it *verbatim*, you must:

- either: individually *escape* it, with `` ` `` (the so-called backtick, PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)):

```bash
.\test.ps1 -link http://testurl`&qdfq  # Note the ` before q
```

- or: enclose it in a [*quoted string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules):

```bash
.\test.ps1 -link 'http://testurl&qdfq'
```

> I'm trying to make the script more user friendly so people don't have to use escape chars, or single/double quotes

- There is *no* way to avoid the techniques above: you *must* satisfy PowerShell's syntax rules in order to make a successful call.
- The only way to avoid escaping or quoting would be to prompt for the URL *interactively*, either explicitly via [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) or implicitly, if you declare the target parameter as `Mandatory` and the user doesn't pass a value in a given invocation.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, tyvm!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @JeffSeb; my pleasure.