# XMLHttpRequest post params containing ampersand

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How would I use XMLHttpRequest if I need to send some parameters that might contain '&' sign (without knowing which one or if any might contain it). Of course if there is an '&' sing it will break parameters on receiving end.

Is there a way to do this without using encodeURIComponent?

Normally I would do this:

```
        var params = 'action='+foo+'&token='+bla+';

        xhrRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhrRequest.readyState == 4) {

                
            }
        }
        xhrRequest.onerror = function(e) { 
           
        };
        xhrRequest.open('POST', url);
        xhrRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhrRequest.send(params);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping ampersand in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Comment: "Is there a way to do this without using encodeURIComponent?" — This doesn't seem like a reasonable requirement. (Admittedly, `encodeURIComponent` isn't a great way of doing it today, but it would solve the problem and you are rejecting it without explanation.)

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to generate `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data by mashing strings together.

Use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API. It will escape characters with special meaning.

XHR can also infer the correct content-type from it, so you don't need to specify it manually.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("action", foo);
params.append("token", bla);

const xhrRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrRequest.onload = function(e) {
}
xhrRequest.onerror = function(e) { 
};
xhrRequest.open('POST', url);
xhrRequest.send(params);
```

Comment: When  I receive these parameters do I need to use rawurldecode?

Comment: @Toniq — What is `rawurldecode`? Are you asking a PHP question now? If you are, then you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) showing your attempt as a [mcve]. (And I wouldn't expect rawurldecode to be used, but a really weird approach to reading the request body might demand it).

Comment: Yes, a simple javascript post to php. I wasnt using rawurldecode so far, just $action= $_REQUEST['action'];

Comment: Have you tried it? (Note that `$_REQUEST` is generally best avoided as it merged `$_COOKIES`, `$_GET` and `$_POST` which makes things (including security) harder to manage).

Comment: So I should use $_POST?

Comment: Generally, yes.